# Finding the sum of maximum difference possible from all subintervals of a given array

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem designing an algorithm. The problem is that this should be executed in O(n) time.

Here is the assignment:
There is an unsorted array "a" with n numbers.

```
mij=min{ai, ai+1, ..., aj}, Mij=max{ai, ai+1, ..., aj}
```

Calculate:

```
S=SUM[i=1,n] { SUM[j=i,n] { (Mij - mij) } }
```

I am able to solve this in O(nlogn) time. This is a university research assignment. Everything that I tried suggests that this is not possible. I would be very thankful if you could point me in the right direction where to find the solution. Or at least prove that this is not possible.

---

Further explanation:

Given `i` and `j`, find the maximum and minimum elements of the array slice a[i:j].  Subtract those to get the range of the slice, `a[max]-a[min]`.

Now, add up the ranges of *all* slices for all (i, j) such that `1 <= i <= j <= n`.  Do it in **O(n)** time.

Comment: Question isn't clear. Please provide correct input and desired output. What is S = SUM[1..n]SUM[i...n](Mij- mij)?

Comment: @SomeDude: that's a double summation, capital sigma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward problem.
I will assume that it is array of objects (like pair of values or tuples) not numbers. First value is index in array and the second is value.

Right question here is how many time we need to multiply each number and add/subtract it from the sum ie in how many sub-sequences it is maximum and minimum element.
This problem is connected to finding next greatest element (nge), you can see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/), just to know it for future problems.

I will write it in pseudo code.

```
subsum (A):
    returnSum = 0
    //i am pushing object into the stack. Firt value is index in array, secong is value
    lastStackObject.push(-1, Integer.MAX_INT)
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        next = stack.pop()
        stack.push(next)
        while (next.value < A[i].value)
            last = stack.pop()
            beforeLast = stack.peek()
            retrunSum = returnSum + last.value*(i-last.index)*(last.index-beforeLast.index)
        stack.push(A[i])

    while stack is not empty:
        last = stack.pop()
        beforeLast = stack.peek()
        retrunSum = returnSum + last.value*(A.length-last.index)*(last.index-beforeLast.index)

    return returnSum

sum(A)
    //first we calculate sum of maximum values in subarray, and then sum of minimum values. This is done by simply multiply each value in array by -1
    retrun subsum(A)+subsum(-1 for x in A.value)
```

Time complexity of this code is O(n).

Peek function is just to read next value in stack without popping it.